# How can I implement an inactivity timeout on an http download

Tags: http, go

I've been reading up on the various timeouts that are available on an http request and they all seem to act as hard deadlines on the total time of a request.

I am running an http download, I don't want to implement a hard timeout past the initial handshake as I don't know anything about my users connection and don't want to timeout on slow connections. What I would ideally like is to timeout after a period of inactivity (when nothing has been downloaded for x seconds). Is there any way to do this as a built in or do I have to interrupt based on stating the file?

The working code is a little hard to isolate but I think these are the relevant parts, there is another loop that stats the file to provide progress but I will need to refactor a bit to use this to interrupt the download:

```
// httspClientOnNetInterface returns an http client using the named network interface, (via proxy if passed)
func HttpsClientOnNetInterface(interfaceIP []byte, httpsProxy *Proxy) (*http.Client, error) {

    log.Printf("Got IP addr : %s\n", string(interfaceIP))
    // create address for the dialer
    tcpAddr := &net.TCPAddr{
        IP: interfaceIP,
    }

    // create the dialer & transport
    netDialer := net.Dialer{
        LocalAddr: tcpAddr,
    }

    var proxyURL *url.URL
    var err error

    if httpsProxy != nil {
        proxyURL, err = url.Parse(httpsProxy.String())
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("Error parsing proxy connection string: %s", err)
        }
    }

    httpTransport := &http.Transport{
        Dial:  netDialer.Dial,
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }

    httpClient := &http.Client{
        Transport: httpTransport,
    }

    return httpClient, nil
}

/*
StartDownloadWithProgress will initiate a download from a remote url to a local file,
providing download progress information
*/
func StartDownloadWithProgress(interfaceIP []byte, httpsProxy *Proxy, srcURL, dstFilepath string) (*Download, error) {

    // start an http client on the selected net interface
    httpClient, err := HttpsClientOnNetInterface(interfaceIP, httpsProxy)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // grab the header
    headResp, err := httpClient.Head(srcURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("error on head request (download size): %s", err)
        return nil, err
    }

    // pull out total size
    size, err := strconv.Atoi(headResp.Header.Get("Content-Length"))
    if err != nil {
        headResp.Body.Close()
        return nil, err
    }
    headResp.Body.Close()

    errChan := make(chan error)
    doneChan := make(chan struct{})

    // spawn the download process
    go func(httpClient *http.Client, srcURL, dstFilepath string, errChan chan error, doneChan chan struct{}) {
        resp, err := httpClient.Get(srcURL)
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        // create the file
        outFile, err := os.Create(dstFilepath)
        if err != nil {
            errChan <- err
            return
        }
        defer outFile.Close()

        log.Println("starting copy")
        // copy to file as the response arrives
        _, err = io.Copy(outFile, resp.Body)

        // return err
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("\n Download Copy Error: %s \n", err.Error())
            errChan <- err
            return
        }

        doneChan <- struct{}{}

        return
    }(httpClient, srcURL, dstFilepath, errChan, doneChan)

    // return Download
    return (&Download{
        updateFrequency: time.Microsecond * 500,
        total:           size,
        errRecieve:      errChan,
        doneRecieve:     doneChan,
        filepath:        dstFilepath,
    }).Start(), nil
}
```

**Update**
Thanks to everyone who had input into this.

I've accepted JimB's answer as it seems like a perfectly viable approach that is more generalised than the solution I chose (and probably more useful to anyone who finds their way here).

In my case I already had a loop monitoring the file size so I threw a named error when this did not change for x seconds. It was much easier for me to pick up on the named error through my existing error handling and retry the download from there.

I probably crash at least one goroutine in the background with my approach (I may fix this later with some signalling) but as this is a short running application (its an installer) so this is acceptable (at least tolerable)

Comment: You could replace `io.Copy` with something you wrote yourself, that sets a timeout for each individual `Read` call and even notifies you about the amount of copied data so far, by writing something to a channel or so.

Comment: That's not a bad solution, feels cleaner than what i had planned - thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Be warned, it is much more complicated to replace `io.Copy` then one thinks, there even was competition to do it, while getting most nice properties: [might be relevant](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/434c3YInH_M/3Qd7C0uDUqQJ)

Comment: Interesting discussion in the link (and link off that to next issue). Having looked at this a bit more, replacing io.Copy is certainly not trivial. It's looking a lot easier to refactor some of my code around the stat monitoring to handle this. I am surprised this doesn't appear to be implemented as part of the std lib. Probably good technical reasons for not doing so but I may submit as a feature request to see what the feedback says, will link in question if I do.

Comment: You can also do this at a lower level, and have a Dialer that returns a net.Conn which implements an idle timeout. This however has the drawback of timing out idle keepalive connections too.

Comment: Note on your approach: that assumes you're fsync'ing the file on every write, which you may be doing, but it's not very efficient. If you're not syncing the file, then the data in the file may not change at all until it's closed.

Comment: Ah, that might explain why my progress monitoring always moves in short bursts regardless of report frequency. Right now I'm trying to get a product out the door and it seems to do the job but I would like to revisit this when I have the time. I'm think the copy function you provided could be used for progress reporting too with a little refactoring around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the copy manually is not particularly difficult. If you're unsure how to properly implement it, it's only a couple dozen lines from the io package to copy and modify to suit your needs (I only removed the `ErrShortWrite` clause, because we can assume that the std library io.Writer implementations are correct)

Here is a copy work-alike function, that also takes a cancelation context and an idle timeout parameter. Every time there is a successful read, it signals to the cancelation goroutine to continue and start a new timer.

```
func idleTimeoutCopy(dst io.Writer, src io.Reader, timeout time.Duration,
    ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc) (written int64, err error) { 
    read := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case <-time.After(timeout):
                cancel()
            case <-read:
            }
        }
    }()

    buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)
    for {
        nr, er := src.Read(buf)
        if nr > 0 {
            read <- nr
            nw, ew := dst.Write(buf[0:nr])
            written += int64(nw)
            if ew != nil {
                err = ew
                break
            }
        }
        if er != nil {
            if er != io.EOF {
                err = er
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return written, err
}
```

While I used `time.After` for brevity, it's more efficient to reuse the `Timer`. This means taking care to use the correct reset pattern, as the return value of the `Reset` function is broken:

```
    t := time.NewTimer(timeout)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        case <-t.C:
            cancel()
        case <-read:
            if !t.Stop() {
                <-t.C
            }
            t.Reset(timeout)
        }
    }
```

You could skip calling `Stop` altogether here, since in my opinion if the timer fires while calling Reset, it was close enough to cancel anyway, but it's often good to have the code be idiomatic in case this code is extended in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the example @JimB, I'm going to have a play with a few ideas and report back. No doubt this would do the job and I may well implement something like this but I'm thinking it would be cleaner in the context of my current code if I just use my existing file stat loop to detect inactivity and kill the copy by closing the response body but I'll have to see how that behaves. Thanks again for the suggestion. up-voted for now, I will probably accept and update the question with my final solution.